# CORS error upload file ~4mb

Tags: node.js, ssl, sails.js, docker, dokku

I'm building an app where angular front-end is on s3 as static website and Sails (0.10.3) API inside dokku with Node 0.11.13 and SSL on EC2. If file is larger than about 4mb I got error "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." OPTIONS request is hitting my API and I can catch it in customMiddleware but the POST with data is not reaching that far. On front-end side I'm using angularjs-file-upload.
If I turn off SSL then it works without any problems but I would prefer to keep it on.

Comment: Are you sure it allows requests larger than 4 MiB ?

Comment: Yes, I'm totally sure. I turned off SSL and then it works without any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went up the chain app itself -> dokku -> SSL and the problem was even higher, in nginx.

nginx.conf required one line more:
proxy_read_timeout 1200s;

Answer (score 3):

One more thing you can try, if it's Nginx that's causing issues. Look into your error log file. Generally its `/var/log/nginx/error.log`
In that if you see this line
`*133774 client intended to send too large body: 3141911 bytes`

It means the issue is of the size and you might wanna fix it.

The way you do it is in your nginx.conf in the HTTP context paste this anywhere.

`client_max_body_size 50M;`

This will allow you to increase your body size to 50M.
Hence fixing the issue

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar solution and I solved it with the help of [this](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-nginx-413-request-entity-too-large/). It's because of the `client_max_body_size` configuration variable that Nginx has.

Answer (score 1):

1.Go to nginx configuration setting file:

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

2.Change in nginx.conf file:

```
http {
clientmaxbody_size 100m;
}
```

3.Restart Your Nginx:

```
sudo service nginx restart 
or 
service nginx reload
```

for my MEAN Stack (node & Expreess js) application it worked.
Hoping for your case too !

```
Another EXPRESS code if 1,2 & 3 point won't work for you
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
```

Below link for reference full detail explanation:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-edit-nginx-setting-for-big-file-upload

Comment: In the 2nd step I got an error and fixed it by changing it like that ```client_max_body_size 100m;```